# Cassandra Node refuses to Join Cluster "Compaction Executor" error

Tags: java, cassandra, nodetool

We have a 3 node Cassandra Cluster running the following version

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Node1 stopped communicating with the rest of the cluster this morning, the logs showed this:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:242] 2020-09-15 19:24:48,753 CassandraDaemon.java:235 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:242,1,main]
ERROR [MutationStage-2] 2020-09-15 19:24:54,749 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[MutationStage-2,5,main]
ERROR [MutationStage-2] 2020-09-15 19:24:54,771 StorageService.java:466 - Stopping gossiper
ERROR [MutationStage-2] 2020-09-15 19:24:56,791 StorageService.java:476 - Stopping native transport
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:242] 2020-09-15 19:24:58,541 LogTransaction.java:277 - Transaction log [md_txn_compaction_c2dbca00-f780-11ea-95eb-cf88b1cae05a.log in /mnt/cass-a/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377] indicates txn was not completed, trying to abort it now
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:242] 2020-09-15 19:24:58,545 LogTransaction.java:280 - Failed to abort transaction log [md_txn_compaction_c2dbca00-f780-11ea-95eb-cf88b1cae05a.log in /mnt/cass-a/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377]
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:242] 2020-09-15 19:24:58,566 LogTransaction.java:225 - Unable to delete /mnt/cass-a/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/md_txn_compaction_c2dbca00-f780-11ea-95eb-cf88b1cae05a.log as it does not exist, see debug log file for stack trace
```

Cassandra starts up fine on the "broken node", but refuses to rejoin the cluster.

When I do a nodetool status I get this:

```
**Error: The node does not have system_traces yet, probably still bootstrapping**
```

Gossip is not running, i've tried disabling and re-enabling, no joy.

I've also tried both a repair and a rebuild, both came back with no errors at all.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms you described indicates to me that the node had some form of hardware failure and the `data/` disk is possibly inaccessible.

In instances like this, the disk failure policy in `cassandra.yaml` kicked in:

```
disk_failure_policy: stop
```

This would explain why gossip is unavailable (on default port `7000`) and the node would not be accepting any client connections either (on default CQL port `9042`).

If there is an impending hardware failure, there's a good chance the disk/volume is mounted as read-only. There's also the possibility that the disk is full. Check the operating system logs for clues and you will likely need to escalate the issue to your sysadmin team. Cheers!

Comment: Hey Erick,

You're correct, it seems the disk policy failure kicked in.

I've tried manually creating a file on the disk and could not.

tI can confirm that The VM did not suffer any "hardware" failures, and the host the vm is running on has many other vm's running on it as well, and all of theose seems fine, as well as the shared storage the vm is connected to.

How do I fix this problem, i've rebooted the vm and cassandra starts fine, but the gossip and client connections are not happening.

Comment: As I said, check that (a) the disk/volume is not mounted as read-only, and (b) the disk is not full. Either of these would prevent gossip from working and would invoke the disk failure policy. Cheers!

Comment: So it turns out it was those pesky inodes #screamingface

Did a nodetool clearsnapshot and that cleared up all the inodes, restarted cassandra and the world is a better place. :)

Thanks for your help Erick.

Comment: Glad to hear you identified the problem. Cheers!